# Reprocess performs all the processing on original image in Paperclip rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I have to accept an image from user

After this, there are several styles in *PaperclipConfig.pic_attachment_options*

```
:convert_options => {
     :max       => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85 -resize 200% -resize 50% -unsharp 1x1+.5+.1',
     :page      => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85 -resize 200% -resize 50% -unsharp 1x1+.5+.1',
     :croppable => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85',
     :thumb     => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85',
     :compressed => '-quality 75',
}
```

Please Note: `convert_options` is performed on original image whereas it should perform on the compressed image

Now in my pic model, I have something like

*has_attached_file :image, PaperclipConfig.pic_attachment_options*

```
def reprocess_image
    return unless adjusting?

    image.reprocess!
end
```

Here image.reprocess! reprocess takes original image itself whereas it should perform all the reprocess on `compressed`  image

There is an option `image.reprocess! :compressed` but it would reprocess only the compressed style and not `max, page, croppable, etc`
My requirement is that reprocess should take compressed image as input rather than original image (keeping original image intact thus reducing the bandwidth usage) and further apply the `convert_options` over the compressed image and thereby reprocess `max, page, croppable, etc` based on compressed image

Here the only goal is, not to process with original image and dump the original image somewhere else and perform entire reprocessing on compressed image